# SQLite scaffolding with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

When I run

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Filename=mydatabase.sqlite3" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
```

I get an empty context

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class mydatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Filename=mydatabse.sqlite3");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong. Is this available for SQLite?

I have a single table in the database with id and name, just a simple example to get me going.

Comment: Please post your solution as an Answer to your question instead.

Comment: Did you noticed the typo in context ? optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Filename=mydatabse.sqlite3") Is **mydatabse.sqlite3** correct ? Looks like is missing an "a" Maybe is not relevant.

Answer (score 17):

It is creating a new database in bin folder because of the relative path in the connection string. I used new connection string.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "DataSource=C:\dev\mydatabase.sqlite3" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
```

Comment: This can be solve the problem, but is not a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Paths are resolved relative to the output directory. (a.k.a. `bin`.) Ensure your database file is copied to the output directory on build.

Do this in csproj by setting **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy if newer**.

Do this on xproj by adding the following to your `project.json`.

```json
{
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "mydatabase.sqlite"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This prompted my to research and experiment. Maybe my notes might be helpful for other people new to this: https://gist.github.com/definedrisk/cadd6925f8fef30ecc3ad35974c153b2

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "DataSource=PATH\mydatabase.sqlite3 "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -OutputDir Models
```