# How to use "dotnet ef scaffold" to create models from a sqlite db?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

The tutorial only tell me how to play with a SQL db.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t Blog -t Post --context-dir Context -c BlogContext
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984456/sqlite-scaffolding-with-entity-framework-core

Comment: Yes, I have tried, may be my query world is unclear. And I finaly find my fault is at the connectionstring, a extra space between Data and Source . QAQ

Answer (score 4):

- Install .NET Core CLI
- Install Ef Tool

  dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
- Make sure to Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Designer and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite in your project
- From project folder run the command:

  dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "data source=C:\dbPath\db.sqlite" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite --output-dir DataModel

Comment: Worked well with: Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools
3.1.8. You only have to replace "dotnet ef" with "dotnet-ef"